# How can i connect frontend with backend and post objects from frontend to backend

Tags: java, angular, spring

So i have the following ngOnInit() for test:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8080/api/answers', { title: 'Angular POST Request Example' });
  }
```

And the following RestController:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ControllerPosting{


    @PostMapping(path="/answers", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody String handlePostRequest(@RequestBody String title){
        //System.out.println(s);
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

What i get on the /api/answers side is:
[image]

Also getting this error in spring:
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' is not supported] but im not using "GET" dont know..

Sadly, i realy don't understand why there is method "GET" and why my post isn't there. Perheps someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: You're trying to access `/api/answer` from the browser address bar directly, which is a `GET` request. That's why you get `GET method not allowed` response. You need to go to the address where the Angular app is running, which I assume is `localhost:4200`

Comment: But i want to have the data at :8080 so at the backend? Or am i wrong?

Comment: So i want to post data to :8080 where the backend is. That the backend can have the data.

Comment: You're not wrong, but there's a misconception. `localhost:8080` is your backend. And you want your frontend (which should be running on a different port) to make a `POST` request to the backend. But you go directly to the backend endpoint from the browser.

Comment: Okei but i dont understand how i should do it then. I thought that i need to send it directly to the backend endpoint.

Comment: You need to go to the `frontend`, and then the frontend will make a `POST` request to your backend.

Comment: Can we chat in a private chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253192/discussion-between-harun-yilmaz-and-benedikt-muller).

Answer (score 1):

By entering `localhost:8080/api/request` in your browser you are sending GET request to `http://localhost:8080/api/request` and **this is your backend not fronted**. You are not handling GET request on the backend - that is why you are getting status 405 (method not allowed).

I bet what you wanted was to enter the fronted. The default port for the angular app is 4200 so you should try to enter into the browser `localhost:4200`